# jquery focus not triggered for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an input field, so when I click any input field, it gets focused.
When I click outside, it focused out.

```
 <input type="text" id="english" name="english"/>

input:active,input:focus{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        if (!($("input").is(":focus"))) {
            alert('not focused');
        }
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DzAwn/59/)

This alert is calling for the first time, if input element is not focused. 
I need it to be called all the time whenever I click outside the input element.

**Update: Second Question**

I have an input field inside iframe, so when I click any input field, it gets focused. But again if I click outside (body area), the iphone keypad is not closed. **Problem with only iphone and ipad inside iframes.** This will work nicely in all browsers. So, I tried if there is no focus, called **`blur()`** or **`document.activeelement`**. but none of them are working.

How to close ipad/iphone keypad when input element is not focused?

Comment: you have not attached any event to it. your code is just checking if the input is focused on document.ready. Attach en event to input field so that it will check everytime you unfocus.

Answer (score 3):

You are not listening for any events, it is not going to keep checking. You need to add an event listener that listens for the blur event on any input.

Comment: Could you help me with any working example? Mainly I need to close iphone/ipad keypad with JS if input is not focused

Answer (score 1):

What epascarello said is correct.  The `if` statement in your `ready` function fires only once when the DOM is finished loading.

Since you are using jQuery, doing what you are trying to do is really easy.

```
<input type="text" id="english" name="english"/>

input:active,input:focus{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And then your JavaScript code:

```
$( "input" ).focusout(function() {
    alert('not focused');
});
```

I can't help you with your second question.

Comment: Do not alert in a blur! use console.log while testing

Comment: Generally I would agree with you but OP is testing this in a JSFiddle where the console output is not immediately visible and therefore whether the code is working is not immediately apparent.  Using an alert() makes it crystal clear that it is actually working.  Also, in this case I tried to leave part of his JS code in place so he would see exactly what it would take to get the the alert he had to fire.

Comment: console is visible in jsfiddle and an alert onblur will create a loop

Comment: this is not calling always right? I need to call inside eventhandler

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  The code above is jQuery syntax for binding an event handler to the focusout event on any input field on the page.  The line with the alert() function on it is what gets called when the event fires (the input field loses focus).